# Black screen, blinking cursor and purple line left

Tags: boot, nvidia, system-installation, multiple-monitors

Last week I installed Ubuntu on my notebook, now I'm also trying to install it on my PC, but with no luck.

When i start from my USB stick (same as I installed my notebook with, Ubuntu 13.04) first I'll see an purple screen, after this it shows a black screen, blinking cursor and the a small line on the left is purple.

I've started searching on Google, and tried the `nomodeset` function on the first black screen. Here it doesn't show the purple line on the left, but still an black screen with blinking cursor..

Now I tried to install 13.10 and 12.10 on the USB stick, but with no luck. Exactly the same things happened.

After this, I tried some other things:

`acpi=off` = Same effect as `nomodeset`.

`nolapic` = Same as "normal" boot (purple line, black screen), but without the blinking cursor.

Desktop specifications:

- Intel Xeon E3-1240 V2
- GeForce GTX 640 Ti BOOST
- 6GB of memory
- 3 displays, the purple line is always on the "main" screen (middle
  one).
- Currently windows 8 pro installed.
- ASRock B75 Pro3-M

Comment: Install nvidia-driver, in dash search for `software & updates`, open it, goto additional driver.

Comment: How can I install anything? it doesn't even boot :S

Comment: Ohh.. Sorry disabled secure boot? See http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/35775 . Also this may be useful too - http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported. Most probably the problem is coming from UEFI

Comment: CSM is enabled, Secure boot is disabled. When i start and open the boot devices, i see USB: PMAP (I always use this) but also UEFI: PMAP. If i select the UEFI one, i get an GRUB screen where i can choose between Try ubuntu, Install Ubuntu, Oem install and check disc for defects.

Comment: And `Confirm-SecureBootUEFI` in `Powershell` returns `Cmdlet not supported {more}`

Answer (score -1):

You could try this and see if it lets you access the desktop:

When hard-drive has stopped loading and you are sitting on a black screen, press CTRL+ALT+F1 and enter your username and password and press ENTER.

Now type: `startx`   which should run xorg and bring you to your desktop...

If this works, open a new Terminal window on your desktop and remove LightDM by typing the following:

```
   sudo apt-get remove lightdm
```

and then done we'll replace it with GDM instead by typing:

```
   sudo apt-get install gdm
```

now type: `sudo reboot`   to reboot computer and hopefully all is well...

Comment: Could the NVIDIA card be the problem? Is that's why you're suggesting this?

Comment: It's one solution to newer machines hanging at bootup, sometimes caused by lightdm or yes, it could be noveau open-source driver hanging on your nvidia card...  Another solution is to press CTRL+ALT+F1 on black screen and typing: sudo apt-get install nvidia-current     in the hope of installing the latest nvidia binaries so your card will be running it's own driver set...